# Why does Moira insist on you getting a mine from Minefield?

Tags: fallout-3

Why can't I just give her a mine I found in the subway system and be done with it? Like, a mine is a mine bro...

Comment: How did they not call this quest The Mines of Moira?

Comment: All mines are not identical; https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Land_mine#Variants

Answer (score 25):

The quest [Wasteland Survival Guide](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Wasteland_Survival_Guide_(quest)) is not about fetching the mine, but writing a book about how to survive in the wastelands. One thing you need to know to survive is to traverse a minefield.

The mine is not the objective, surviving the minefield (with proof) so she can write it down for her book is.

Comment: but why did it have to be THAT minefield?

Comment: @Dave. In universe, because that's the closest and first minefield that came to Moira's mind. Out of universe, because the devs didn't want to go through the extra trouble of making every possibly minefield a valid target. Those would be the most likely explanations.

Comment: easy solution, if at any point you disabled a mine and collected it, Moira would accept it

Comment: @Dave, except there are plenty of places in the game that are not minefields, but have armed mines as trap. Your "easy solution" would allow players to simply drop an armed mine on the ground, disarm and collect it, then lie to Moira about going to Minefield. You can do that already, see my answer.

Comment: have it so that mines placed by the player act differently than those in minefields

Comment: @Dave, you forgot all the places that *aren't* minefields. From Wikipedia: "*A [minefield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minefield_(disambiguation)) is an area covered with land mines or naval mines.*" A room with one or two mines is *not* an "area *covered* in mines", and there are plenty of those in the game. Even if there *was* an "easy solution", Bethesda didn't implement it. Why they didn't would fall into "game design and intent", which is off-topic on this site.

Comment: I'd consider two mines in a room a minefield

Comment: @Dave, well the game doesn't. As for why it doesn't: "*Questions about **Game Design and Development** are off topic. This includes speculative questions about developer intent, with respect to both mechanics and narrative. You might want to ask over at [GameDev.SE](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/), but be sure to read [their FAQ](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)*"

Comment: @Dave `but why did it have to be THAT minefield?`  Well, she is writing a book.   She heard stories about a ghost town and a minefield in it.    Imagine she's done a lot of research on *that* minefield and incorporated information from *multiple* stories into a chapter she is writing on minefields.   To cap it off, she actually got someone to go to the minefield and bring her one of the mines which she can describe in detail.     Satisfying for a book, yes?  Compare that with the same thing but with her getting a mine from someone they found in a subway tunnel.

Comment: One mine is not a minefield.  @Dave, at least, considers two mines a minefield.  I'd say, if I saw a sign that said "Minefield ahead" I'd expect there to me more than two, or even more than four or five mines in the area ahead  Man, what is a minefield, and how did this turn into a discussion of the paradox of the heap?

Comment: Are there any places in fallout 3 that has only one mine?

Answer (score 12):

Because Moira is writing the [Wasteland Survival Guide](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Wasteland_Survival_Guide), and wants you to try and survive an existing minefield.

She also points out the following in advance:

> I need someone to research how to travel through a minefield.
>
> I've heard stories about a ghost town that's just full of mines. Traders just call the place "Minefield."
>
> Sounds like the place for some fieldwork! Get in there, get back, and tell me all about it. And could you bring back a mine for my studies?

Answer (score 8):

Since others have already addressed the question in the title, I'll address the question in the body:

> why can't I just give her a mine I found in the subway system and be done with it?

According to the [Fallout fandom](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Wasteland_Survival_Guide_(quest)), **you actually can**:

> As frag mines are quite prevalent in the game, it is possible to lie to Moira about visiting Minefield and still complete the optional objective to complete the quest.

Do keep in mind that the outcome of this quest can change based on whether you lied to Moira or not.

Comment: I feel that's not the same at all, either you lie to her or she won't accept the objective as complete, no middle grounds

Comment: @Dave, here's the thing: Moira *doesn't* insist you go to Minefield. She wants you to go through a minefield, gives you an example of one, and that's where the game expects you to go. If this weren't a game, Moira might accept a mine from any minefield. But it *is* a game. One made by people who can't spend all eternity to map out all possible ways you could've solved this quest, including building your own custom minefield. So, no, there is no middle ground because the game wasn't designed to have a middle ground. If you want to know "why not", sadly game design questions are off topic here.

Comment: any mine not layed by the player counts as a "minefield" that's an easy solution, doesn't take all that long to program, and makes Moira less of a prick

Comment: @Dave, your easy solution means the player can simply drop a single mine on the ground, and collect it back. Moira is asking you to *navigate a minefield*, not to *disarm a mine*. The point is to teach people how to survive the wastelands, not to train bomb disposal technicians. Disarming and collecting a mine is just the ***optional*** objective, not the objective itself.

Comment: I very specifically said the mine has to not be set by the player

Comment: @Dave, then I misunderstood. Sorry. But I think we're veering off-topic here. Moira is just a character in a game. She doesn't make the rules. The game does. Moira wants to write about *navigating a minefield* and gives you an example of one. It's the *game* that forces you to visit Minefield and ignores any other location, not Moira. Whether or not the solution is easy, Bethesda designed this quest that way. Why? That's off-topic here. You just have to accept that this game has limitations, whether you like it or not.

Comment: @Nolonar "Sounds like the place for some fieldwork!   Get in there, get back, and tell me all about it!"  - It does sound like she wants you to go to that specific minefield.   As I mentioned in another comment, it makes sense to me that she would want to tell a compelling story in her book about a known minefield she has already researched and the brave adventurer's own experiences when going there.